# Django custom login decorator checking if session exists

Tags: python, django, function, django-sessions

I am trying to implement a custom login in Django utilizing a custom auth Backend. These are the steps

1. Initialize session when the user is authenticated
2. write a custom decorator to wrap in the views (login_required)

I get: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session'`

I actually need to implement this as decorator:

```
if not request.session.get('user_logged_in_custom_backend'):
        return redirect('/login')
```

view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
def login(request):
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user:
            request.session['user_id'] = user.pk

def login_required_custom(request):
    return request.session.get('user_id') or False


@user_passes_test(login_required_custom, login_url='/login/')
def HomePage(request):
   return HttpResponse('Only login users should access this page')
```

Comment: You've made a typo in the penultimate line, I'm assuming `def(request):` should be `def my_view(request):`

Comment: `HomePage` should return at least something, django will error otherwise. Also, can you provide the full traceback for the error.

Comment: The function passed to `user_passes_test` should be a function accepting a single argument, that argument should be the user, not the request

Comment: user is an anonymous user that is authenticated from a custom backend. I need to check if that session exists. If not, redirect the user to another page. Exactly what `@login_required` does but from a custom backend checking if session exists

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure the best way to do that, but a few reflections:
1) You shouldn't be using `user_passes_test` this way. It's purpose is to see if a particular user passes a test, it does not recieve the request.
2) It feels like your trying to do some things that django's session framework should be doing. You might be best reading up how to customise django's session framework rather than completely reimplimenting it. The docs are quite good IIRC